# How to extract the SES from summary of an EcosimR output

Tags: r

I'm trying to automate the extraction of the standardized effect size from the output of a summary function so I can automate plotting downstream.

Specifically, I'm summarizing the output of `cooc_null_model(x=co-occurrence_data)` and I'd like to output the "Standardized Effect Size (SES)" which is the final value in the printed results.

How would I go about doing this?

example code from help section:

```
library(EcoSimR)

## Run the null model 
finchMod <- cooc_null_model(dataWiFinches, algo = "sim9", nReps = 10000, burn_in = 500)

## Summary and plot info 
summary(finchMod)
```

I was hoping it'd be something of the sort: `finchMod$Standardized_Effect_Size` but I can't seem to find the target value through those means.

Any and all help is appreciated!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an account of what I have done to find out where is your statistic of interest, SES.

**Step one:**

Run the model and check

```
class(finchMod)
#[1] "coocnullmod"

str(finchMod)
#List of 13
# $ Obs            : num 3.79
# $ Sim            : num [1:10000] 2.59 2.59 2.59 2.59 2.6 ...
# $ Elapsed.Time   : chr "1.7 secs"
# $ Time.Stamp     : chr "Fri Jun 22 18:35:52 2018"
# $ Metric         : chr "c_score"
# $ Algorithm      : chr "sim9"
# $ N.Reps         : num 10000
# $ SaveSeed       : logi FALSE
# $ RandomSeed     : NULL
# $ Randomized.Data: num [1:17, 1:19] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 ...
#  ..- attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
#  .. ..$ : NULL
#  .. ..$ : chr [1:19] "Cuba" "Hispaniola" "Jamaica" "Puerto_Rico" #...
# $ Data           : num [1:17, 1:19] 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 ...
#  ..- attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
#  .. ..$ : NULL
#  .. ..$ : chr [1:19] "Cuba" "Hispaniola" "Jamaica" "Puerto_Rico" #...
# $ burn.in        : num 500
# $ burn.in.metric : num [1:500] 3.68 3.68 3.65 3.65 3.65 ...
# - attr(*, "class")= chr "coocnullmod"
```

As you can see, there is no SES. This means that its value is computed by the method `summary.coocnullmod` or by some function this method calls. See, for instance, [R FAQ 8.1](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/FAQ/R-FAQ.html#How-should-I-write-summary-methods_003f).

**Step two:**

Check the code of `summary.coocnullmod`. At an R prompt, the name of a function without parenthesis prints its body.

```
summary.coocnullmod
Error: object 'summary.coocnullmod' not found
```

So use `getAnywhere`.

```
getAnywhere(summary.coocnullmod)
A single object matching ‘summary.coocnullmod’ was found
It was found in the following places
  registered S3 method for summary from namespace EcoSimR
  namespace:EcoSimR
with value

function (object, ...) 
{
   nullmodObj <- object

   [...etc...]
   [...last code line...]

    cat("Standardized Effect Size (SES): ", format((nullmodObj$Obs - 
        mean(nullmodObj$Sim))/sd(nullmodObj$Sim), digits = 5), 
        "\n")
}
<environment: namespace:EcoSimR>
```

**Step three:**

So now you have everything that is needed to automate your computation of the SES.

```
ses <- function(object){
  (object$Obs - mean(object$Sim))/sd(object$Sim)
}

ses(finchMod)
#[1] 5.69756
```